# Converting an AS3 snippet to AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript

First of all, i want to apologize for my poor English for it is not my first language.

I need help with converting a piece of AS3 script to AS2 and i know its a bit of a "Can you do this for me" question, but i really can't manage to sort it out.

This is the piece of script that needs to be converted to AS2:

```
var url:String = "http://media.admeen.com/branding/branding01.swf";
var w:int = 100;
var h:int = 100;

branding_def.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
branding_def.buttonMode = true;
branding_def.useHandCursor = true;
function onClickHandler(event:MouseEvent){
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.lng = Capabilities.language;
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://media.admeen.com/branding/forward.php");
    request.data = variables;
    try {
        navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
    } catch (e:Error) {
        trace("Error: ");
    }
}

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, success);
if(Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE){
    var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
    loader.load(new URLRequest(url), context);
} else {
    loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
}

function success(evt:Event):void{
    var branding:MovieClip = MovieClip(evt.target.content);
    if (contains(branding_def)) removeChild(branding_def);
    var fX = (w/branding.loaderInfo.width);
    var fY = (h/branding.loaderInfo.height);
    addChild(this.scaleToFit(branding,(branding.width*fX),(branding.height*fY)));
}

function scaleToFit(mc:MovieClip, maxW:int, maxH:int):MovieClip{
    maxH = maxH == 0 ? maxW : maxH;
    mc.width = maxW;
    mc.height = maxH;
    mc.scaleX < mc.scaleY ? mc.scaleY = mc.scaleX : mc.scaleX = mc.scaleY;
    return mc;
}
```

I really hope you can help me with this!

Kind regards

Comment: Why would you convert to an older actionscript?

Comment: It's to be used in older Flash files

Comment: Your English is hardly anything to be apologizing for.  You write like a native speaker of a non-American dialect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think it's possible to do AS2 even if you know what you're doing without having the [language reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=Part2_AS2_LangRef_1.html) open.

The biggest issue you'll have is that the concept of events is very primitive and backward. For most Classes, there's sort of a callback thingie going on. And scope is all wonky. It looks like you're using timeline code instead of proper Classes, so you probably won't have scope issues. For some reason this acts differently from frame scripts vs. Classes. If you do have issues, look at the [Delegate Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00002284.html).

Some other notable things you want to look at:
MovieClip [onPress](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001337.html#395593)
MovieClip [loadMovie](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001318.html#389585)

Good luck, and post back if this isn't enough to get you there.